# How to implement Caching in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, caching

I am working on a existing application , where it was designed in such a way that even for some static data it queries MongoDB . (Indexing has been done on the MongoDB collections) , due to this  application is slow .

(The data in MongoDB is huge , and the Mongo DB Version we are using is 2.1)

I have read about MongoDB caching , but i am not sure how to implement that ??

Please let me know how to do Caching in Mongo DB ??

Please suggest a  better aproach for solving this .

Comment: Were you able to caching in Spring Boot using Spring Data Mongo ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Covered Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries)?

A **Covered Query** is a query in which:

all the fields in the query are part of an index, and

all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.

Alternatively, you could maintain `config` files for storing static data as long as it's not passwords. [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) is pretty easy to get started with.

Comment: Sagar , If i implement the Covered Queries , wouldn't i would be disturbing the existing index created on that collection ??

Comment: Preethi, Why? Can't you add multiple indexes on a key?

Comment: In some queries we are returning the whole record of a Collection , In that case do we need to run the db.coll.ensureIdex on all those fields of that collection ?? and some of the fields in that collection are updated frequently by 3rd party Server , so will it be not a problem ??

Comment: Using Covered Queries means you add indexes to all the fields you return as part of your query. So, yes - you will add indexes to all the fields that you return. I'd run a bunch of tests and compare the results. If a set of fields are updated frequently, maybe they could be in a smaller collection that doesnt use indexes. It all depends on how you design your schema.